# Spring mvc does not find my /opt/ path

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to access to static resources outside context root with spring mvc (yes, it's possible), but the "file:/opt/final-test/target/**" is red and I cannot access to anything. (404).

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/generatedThumbnails/" location="file:/opt/final-test/target/**" />
```

I already tried to put  :

```
file:/opt/final-test/target/**
file:/opt/final-test/target/
file:/opt/final-test/target
```

but nothing is good.

Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: Does your user have permission to read that location?

Comment: I did a chmod 777 -R /opt

Comment: ...and of course, I try to access with http://localhost:8080/generatedThumbnails/2b5bc292-9bee-4522-86bd-a098aaaa8100.png

Comment: Add two stars: mapping="/generatedThumbnails/**". Actually that just lets you add other folders. Ignore this.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much ! But I don't understand totally because I don't have subfolders in /opt/final-test/target/... Anyway. Problem solved.

Comment: Well, it might have been nice if you'd said, hey, you were right, put the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just deleted my answer if you wanna put your... I was just curious to test the link to answer myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two stars to the mapping /generatedThumbnails/** :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/generatedThumbnails/**" location="file:/opt/final-test/target/**" />
```